# How to generate documentation of robot file using sphinx?

Tags: latex, robotframework, python-sphinx, pdflatex

I have a robot file (calc_check.robot) in which each test case has separate documentation.

```
*** Settings *** 
Documentation 
...         The test cases are designed to test the calculator .

Library       ../../Library/AddNumbers


*** Test Cases ***
Calc_check_test Testcase01_a
[Documentation]
...      Verify that two numbers are added or not
[Tags]      add    calculator
${addition}=     Add numbers    10    20 

Calc_check_test Testcase01_b
[Documentation]
...      Verify that two numbers are added or not with negative sign
[Tags]      add    calculator
${addition}=     Add numbers    10    -20
```

When i try to generate documentation for that robot file using the rst file (call_check.rst) i'm getting complete test case along with documentation as well, but i need only "[Documentation]" part only.

```
calc_check
======================================

.. robot-settings::
   :source:/Users/sphinx/calc_check.robot

.. robot-tests::
   :source:/Users/sphinx/calc_check.robot
```

I want documentation (i.e., only [Documentation] part of test case) from two test cases excluding the test case code.

Please tell me how to generate only the documentation part of it.

Comment: Are you using an extension for sphinx to support robot framework files? You say you have a robot file named `calc_check.robot` but are using sphinx with `call_check.rst`. How are you creating the .rst file from the .robot file?

Answer (score 1):

Robot provides documentation generation libraries called **libdoc**:

https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/2.9.2/_modules/robot/libdoc.html

Problem is that it generates only for libraries and resources files (those without ***Testcase*** part).

If you need to generate docs from test suites, I would recommand to temporary change TestSuite into Resource file (change section to Keywords) and run libdoc for such file:

```
python -m robot.libdoc <path to res/lib> <list/show>
```

Comment: I'm using Sphinx "make html" command for generating the document, so please suggest me the changes need to be made in .rst file. So that it'll generate only document part of robot.

Comment: please add someone you know who can help. Thanks in advance.